# Springfox Swagger: Could not resolve pointer: /definitions/Instant

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, springfox

We have a SpringBoot project, and we're using Springfox Swagger for generating the API documentation.

There's a response class that contains:

```
private Collection<Instant> quartzScheduledDates;
```

When I run SwaggerUI, I receive this message:

> Errors Resolver error at
>   paths./subscriptions/{subscriptionIdStr}.get.responses.200.schema.properties.quartzScheduledDates.items.$ref
>   Could not resolve reference because of: Could not resolve pointer:
>   /definitions/Instant does not exist in document

We're using Springfox Swagger 2.9.2, SpringBoot 2.1.2-RELEASE.

I've also tried using the Docket trick in springfox, as seen in [Springfox Documentation](https://springfox.github.io/springfox/docs/current/):

```
    docket.directModelSubstitute(Instant.class, java.util.Date.class);
```

With no success - same error message.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your response should not be a problem(I just tested). Please post your endpoint and its configuration or even better create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was able to replicate this issue.
[image]

This can be resolved by defining new **AlternateTypeRules** while creating Docket for your SWAGGER.

Below is the snippet.

```
Docket docket= new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .alternateTypeRules( AlternateTypeRules.newRule(
                    typeResolver.resolve(Collection.class, Instant.class),
                    typeResolver.resolve(Collection.class, Date.class), Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE))
            .select()
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.test"))
            .paths(PathSelectors.any())
            .build();
```

Comment: Thank you :) @VladDinulescu

Comment: worked for List<LocalDate> in my case:
    TypeResolver typeResolver = new TypeResolver();
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)         
        .alternateTypeRules(AlternateTypeRules.newRule(
            // my model List<LocalDate>
            typeResolver.resolve(List.class, LocalDate.class),
            // alternate for JSON definition
            typeResolver.resolve(List.class, String.class), Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE))
  ...

Comment: typeResolver type is `com.fasterxml.classmate.TypeResolver`.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had to be really specific. I had:

```
TreeSet<ZonedDateTime>
```

Then I had to specifically add:

```
AlternateTypeRules.newRule(
    typeResolver.resolve(TreeSet.class, ZonedDateTime.class),
    typeResolver.resolve(TreeSet.class, Date.class), Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE))
```

It did **NOT** work with a parent interface such as: `Collection`, `Set`, etc. in the typeResolver. (TypeResolver is @AutoWired by the way if you wonder where it comes from. See docs: https://springfox.github.io/springfox/docs/current/)