# Swagger resolver error - could not resolve pointer

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger

I have a Spring controller method as follows.

```
@PutMapping("/update")
public ResponseEntity<String> updateMethod(@RequestBody() ListDto listDto) {
...
}
```

The input parameter should be an instance of the `ListDto` class. The ListDto class is as follows.

```
@Data
@ApiModel(description = "update list dto")
public class ListDto extends ArrayList<ObjectDto> {
}
```

The `ObjectDto` class is as follows.

```
@Data
@ApiModel(description = "update object dto")
public class ObjectDto {
    @ApiModelProperty(example = "1")
    private String id;

    @ApiModelProperty(example = "new message")
    private String message;
}
```

The issue is, when trying to use the method in Swagger, I get the below error - seems like the swagger definition for the `ObjectDto` class does not get created at runtime.

[image]
Is there a way to force the definition to get created and make this error disappear?

Comment: 1) What version of Springfox do you use? 2) Do these answers help? -- [Could not resolve pointer: /definitions/Error-ModelName](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67786004/113116), [Springfox Swagger: Could not resolve pointer: /definitions/Instant](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54927303/113116), [Swagger with Spring WebFlux cannot find Publisher«ResponseEntity«object»»](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65179918/113116)

Comment: @Helen thanks for mentioning these links and this answer resolved my issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63662483/could-not-resolve-pointer-definitions-error-modelname/67786004#67786004

Comment: If someone else is having a similar issue, you can solve it by adding another configuration to the Docket Bean like this:                                 `.additionalModels(typeResolver.resolve(ObjectDto.class) )`

Answer (score -4):

Try and reinstall your schema.
To do so You can Simply reinstall swagger!

Comment: could you please explain/link how to do so?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: To do so you can simply reinstall Swagger!